# Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException, Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: java, php, android, json, pdo

i am trying to set up a login page with JSON, PDO and MySQL. I have triple checked my code and it still doesnt seem to be working. The logcat seems to be showing that the JSON parser is failing to read the responses from the pdo page but when i test it with a form, my JSON responses are displayed. Please help me

My Login Activity:

```
Button btnLogin;
TextView passreset;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputPassword;
private TextView ForgotPass;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/ZCASPlatform/login.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernametxt);
    inputPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordtxt);
    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    ForgotPass =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.passres);

     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {
         public void onClick(View v)
            {

                {
                        new AttemptLogin().execute();
                }
            } 
     });
}




class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args)
    {
        int success;
        String username = inputUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        try
        {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            Log.d("request!", "starting");

             JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
             Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
             success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

             if (success == 1)
             {
                 Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                 Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                 finish();
                 startActivity(i);
                 return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
             }
             else
             {
                 Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                 return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
             }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url)
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }   
}
```

My JSONParser :

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

My login.php

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $query = "SELECT id, username, password FROM user WHERE username = :username";
    $query_params = array(':username' => $_POST ['username']);

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result =$stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Login Error.Please Try Again";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    $validated_info = false;
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if ($row)
    {
        if($_POST['password'] === $row['password'])
        {
            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }
    if ($login_ok)
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login Successful";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    else
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
}
```

And finally the response from my logcat is as follows:

04-06 16:51:51.513: E/Buffer Error(22626): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 16:51:51.518: E/JSON Parser(22626): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: Is your variable `is` null?

Comment: yes, it is initialised as null

Comment: Then when you call `is.close()` you're getting a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: so i shouldnt initialise it as null?

Comment: You need to check if it's null before dereferencing it. Attach a debugger and walk through the code to understand what's happening.